# Auth0: User to be acted on does not match subject in bearer token

Tags: auth0

{"statusCode":403,"error":"Forbidden","message":"User to be acted on does not match subject in bearer token.","errorCode":"unowned_resource"}

```
   curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
 CURLOPT_URL => "https://XXXXXXXXX.auth0.com/api/v2/users    /auth0|XXXXXXXXX",
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "PATCH",
  CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => json_encode($postpassword),
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    "authorization: Bearer ".$accesstoken,
    "content-type: application/json"
  ),
));
```

Hope this is something related to settings in auth0 configuration.

Can any one help on about this error..

Comment: I have the same problem. Did you figure out anything?

Comment: Same error here!

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and I figured out a solution for me.

I missed some scopes for my application. Under `APIs`, `Auth0 Management API`, `Machine to Machine Applications` expand your application (click the downward arrow besides the `Authorized` switch) and add `read:users` and maybe `read:users_app_metadata`.

Comment: In my case, I was missing `update` scopes. Once I added those, I was getting successful response.